# Android Listfragment relace page name to icon

Tags: android, icons

My app have android listfragment, 3 pages with 3 title i want replace page title to a icon how can i?

```
  public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new firstFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new secondFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new thirdFragment();
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.fragment_one).toUpperCase();
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.fragment_two).toUpperCase();
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.fragment_three).toUpperCase();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want each page have a icon not a text title. And also how can i aligh each icon in center

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom ActionBar and set some Layout. When your fragment will start then you can set you icon there, update style or something else...

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the tabs in action bar and you can set the Drawables for each tab u want.

Comment: private String[] tabs = { TabIcons }                               // Adding Tabs
for (String tab_icons : tabs) {        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(tab_icons) .setTabListener(this));
  }